# Emphasizing and adding symbols to a definition

Tags: numbering, underline

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\underline{Def}}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{definition}}
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \chapter{Partial Derivatives}
    Contrary to the previous chapter, now we will deal with functions of several variables along with their continuity, derivative, and intgeral behavior.
    \begin{definition}
        Fibration A fibration
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

When creating a new definition for the chapter, this is the following output.
[image: Output]

I was wondering how I could make it so that the whole term "Def 3.1" is underlined, and also how to make a colon appear after the 1 instead of a period.

Thanks! (Beginner at Latex)

Update 1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove = 6pt, spacebelow = 6pt, headpunct={:} ,postfoothook=\noindent\hspace{-\fontdimen2\font}]{mydef}

\declaretheorem[parent=chapter,name = Def,style = mydef]{definition}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{definition}}

\declaretheorem[numbered = no,style = mydef, name = Example]{example}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \chapter{Partial Differentiation}
    Contrary to the previous chapter, now we will discuss the continuity and differentiation of functions of several variables.
    \begin{definition}
        Let $D$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e: $$D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 = \{(x,y) \mid x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in\mathbb{R} \}$$
        We say that $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued function of two variables, if it assigns a real number $f(x,y)\, \mathrm{to\,each}\, (x,y) \in D.$ The \emph{range} of $f$ is the set of real numbers that $f$ maps to, $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
    \end{definition}
    \begin{example}
        Let $f(x,y) = \sin(x^2y) \leadsto D = {\mathbb{R}}^2\, , R\rightarrow \left[-1,-1 \right] $
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Underlining is very bad typographic practice, which dates back to the times of typewriter, when it ws not easy to have access to italic of boldface characters. That said, you can take a look at the `thmtools`package, which cooperates efficiently with `amsthm`.

Comment: Oh I see, okay. I have downloaded thmtools and reading up on its documentation. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  a code with `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{amsthm, thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt, spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\mdseries, notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct ={:},
headformat=\underline{\NAME~\NUMBER \NOTE},
bodyfont=\normalfont,
postheadspace=1em,
]{mydef}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\declaretheorem[style=mydef, name=Def, parent=chapter, preheadhook = \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}]{definition}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \chapter{Partial Derivatives}

    Contrary to the previous chapter, now we will deal with functions of several variables along with their continuity, derivative, and integral behavior.
    \begin{definition}[A silly definition]
        Fibration A fibration
    \end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have taken the syntax that I needed from your code and cut down some parts that I thought were a bit too specific in defining the detail and now it looks perfect. I have taken your advice of removing the underline. I will post my new code below if you would like to critique it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[headpunct={:}]{mydef}

\declaretheorem[parent=chapter,style = mydef]{definition}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{definition}}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \chapter{Partial Derivatives}
    \begin{definition}[A silly definition]
        Let $D$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just discovered that for `amsthm` the default font for theorem title is roman bold, so you're right to nott write values for the head font. However you should add values  for `spaceabove` and `spacebelow`: if you test it with some text above and below, the vertical spacing is *very* tight.

Comment: Indeed, there was basically no space between text above and below, so I have changed it to 6pt. One question: For some reason the text below is indented one full tab farther than the text above the definition. I'm not sure why that's happening ;/

Comment: It's the normal paragraph indent. If you find it's too large, you can change its value with `\parindent=…` in the preamble (a usual value is `1em`). If you don't want it just at the beginning of some specific paragaphs, add `\noindent`.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. The reason I don't want it to indent is because I want it to line up with the word "Definition", as the text above happens to be aligned with. Thank you for all the help and sorry for the burden.

Comment: You're no burden. I'll test for an automatic solution.

Comment: Add the following last optional argument for `\declaretheoremstyle`: `,postfoothook=\noindent\hspace{-\fontdimen2\font}`

Comment: Wow, that makes the spacing much cleaner. I'll add a new answer below with the total code I have come with so far and a picture of the layout. Assuming you've written mathematic notes before, any advice you have for outlining would be appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: Preferably, add the code to the question (mentioning it's an update, so that everyone can see it).

Comment: Yes you make a good point, as to not cluster the whole post with multiple answers. I added an updated code and picture to the original question :)